# Password input (python3)

Tags: python

I'm working on a project which signs into your email account for you using python 3. I can't install getpass.getpass() and I couldn't find a good site that would have a solution. I'm trying to hide the user input on the password input so nobody could see it.
Ex.

> username = input("Enter your username/n")
>
> password = input("Enter your password:/n") # I can't figure out how to hide the input on this line.

Comment: You're looking for [getpass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html)

Comment: There's another method at the bottom of the duplicate. Also, why can't you install getpass?

Comment: You don't have to install `getpass`. That's part of the standard library.

Comment: I can't install it because I'm using an application called WinPython and getpass won't install for some reason.